# Passing dyanmic querysets to Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to pass a dynamic queryset from `views.py` to my django template (`company_detail.html`) based off whether there are notes of a particular "note type."
[image: Exmaple image]
I have a "notes" model which is related to "Company" model, as shown:

```
models.py

class Company(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    address = AddressField(null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class Notes(models.Model):
    NOTE_CHOICES = [
        ('sales_structure', 'Sales Structure'),
        ('product_prefs', 'Product Preferences'),
        ('personnel', 'Personnel'),
        ('misc', 'Miscellaneous')
    ]
    account = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')
    note_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=NOTE_CHOICES)
    note_text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

My view uses `django.views.generic.base.View` as follows:

```
views.py

class CompanyDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        contact_table = ContactTable(Contact.objects.filter(account=self.kwargs.get('pk')))
        notes = Notes.objects.filter(account=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        note_types = []
        for type in Notes.NOTE_CHOICES:
            text = type[1]
            notes_sub = notes.filter(note_type=type[0])
            quant = notes_sub.count()
            if quant > 0:
                note_types.append((text, quant, notes_sub))
        notes_form = NoteForm(account=company)
        return render(request,
            'companies/company_detail.html',
                {'company': company,
                 'notes': notes,
                 'note_types': note_types,
                 'note_form': notes_form,
                 'contact_table': contact_table
                 },
        )
```

Which is passed to template:

```
<h3>Account Notes</h3>
        <div class="accordion" id="NotesAccordion">
            {% for type in note_types %}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id=Heading_{{ type.0 }}>
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=#{{ type.0 }} aria-expanded="false" aria-controls={{ type.0 }}>
                                {{ type.0 }} ({{ type.1 }})
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id={{ type.0 }} class="collapse" aria-labelledby=heading_{{ type.0 }} data-parent="#NotesAccordion">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          {% for note in {{ type.3 }} %}
                          
                          {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I'd like to have however many `<div class="card">`'s as there are subjects USED, which is currently working, but what's NOT working is then displaying only the corresponding notes in each respective `<div class="card-body">`.

`{% for note in {{ type.3 }} %}` is the problem.  Can anyone suggest another way to accomplish this?  I want it to be dynamic so I don't have to re-write my `views.py` and `company_detail.html` should my note choices change at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get this to work by using a custom inclusion template tag, which was only a few extra lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try doing this

```
def view(request):
   sales_structure =  Notes.objects.filter(note_type='sales_structure')
   personnel =  Notes.objects.filter(note_type='personnel')

context = {
    'sales_structure' : sales_structure,
    'personnel' : personnel,
    
}
```

this way you can just loop through each context in you template, which is going to get the particular item related to the choice

Comment: Ya that was my fallback, but didn't want to have to hardcode it into the view/template in case my note_types changed at any point (likely) in the future.  Wanted the whole thing to be dynamic.  Appreciate it though!